# WCF: The service certificate is not provided. Specify a service certificate in ServiceCredentials

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-4.0

I'm trying to create a WCF service that uses the `MembershipProvider` for authentication. Because it is an internal service I'm currently not interested in applying transport level security (HTTPS) **and I want to (for now) do this without a certificate**. Besides, this will complicate rolling out the service and I wish to do this at a later point in time. I've built a basic configuration (even without configuring the `MembershipProvider`, but WCF keeps throwing me the following exception:

> The service certificate is not provided. Specify a service certificate
>   in ServiceCredentials.

Here's my configuration:

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <ws2007HttpBinding>
      <binding name="Service1WS2007HttpBindingConfig">
        <security mode="Message">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </ws2007HttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:9800/Service1.svc"
        binding="ws2007HttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="Service1WS2007HttpBindingConfig"
        contract="WcfService1.IService1" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false">
    <serviceActivations>
      <add relativeAddress="Service1.svc" service="WcfService1.Service1" />
    </serviceActivations>
  </serviceHostingEnvironment>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Stacktrace of the exception:

> [InvalidOperationException: The service certificate is not provided.
>   Specify a service certificate in ServiceCredentials. ]
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.ServiceCredentialsSecurityTokenManager.CreateServerX509TokenProvider()
>   +12382737    System.ServiceModel.Security.ServiceCredentialsSecurityTokenManager.CreateLocalSecurityTokenProvider(RecipientServiceModelSecurityTokenRequirement
>   recipientRequirement) +63
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.ServiceCredentialsSecurityTokenManager.CreateSecurityTokenProvider(SecurityTokenRequirement
>   requirement) +48
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.ServiceCredentialsSecurityTokenManager.CreateTlsnegoServerX509TokenProvider(RecipientServiceModelSecurityTokenRequirement
>   recipientRequirement) +191
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.ServiceCredentialsSecurityTokenManager.CreateTlsnegoSecurityTokenAuthenticator(RecipientServiceModelSecurityTokenRequirement
>   recipientRequirement, Boolean requireClientCertificate,
>   SecurityTokenResolver& sctResolver) +683
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.ServiceCredentialsSecurityTokenManager.CreateSecurityTokenAuthenticator(SecurityTokenRequirement
>   tokenRequirement, SecurityTokenResolver& outOfBandTokenResolver)
>   +12383208    System.ServiceModel.Security.SessionRenewSecurityTokenManager.CreateSecurityTokenAuthenticator(SecurityTokenRequirement
>   tokenRequirement, SecurityTokenResolver& outOfBandTokenResolver) +81
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SymmetricSecurityProtocolFactory.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +181
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +21
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +318
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityListenerSettingsLifetimeManager.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +94
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +240
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +318
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +72
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The ChannelDispatcher at
>   'http://localhost:9800/Service1.svc' with contract(s)
>   '"IssueAndRenewSession"' is unable to open its IChannelListener.]
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +118
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +318    System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +111
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +318
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenAuthenticator.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +131
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +21
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +318
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.CommunicationObjectSecurityTokenAuthenticator.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +20
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionServerSettings.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +792
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +21
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +318
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityListenerSettingsLifetimeManager.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +148
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +240
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +318
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +72
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The ChannelDispatcher at
>   'http://localhost:9800/Service1.svc' with contract(s) '"IService1"' is
>   unable to open its IChannelListener.]
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +118
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +318    System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +111
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +318
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath) +206
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath) +651
>
> [ServiceActivationException: The service '/Service1.svc' cannot be
>   activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception
>   message is: The ChannelDispatcher at
>   'http://localhost:9800/Service1.svc' with contract(s) '"IService1"' is
>   unable to open its IChannelListener..]
>   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +688590
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   result) +190
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.ExecuteSynchronous(HttpApplication
>   context, String routeServiceVirtualPath, Boolean flowContext, Boolean
>   ensureWFService) +234
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule.ProcessRequest(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +359
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +148    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75

What is wrong with my configuration and how can I solve this?

Comment: [This blog post](http://webservices20.blogspot.nl/2008/11/introducing-wcf-clearusernamebinding.html) gives the answer.

Comment: See http://webservices20.blogspot.nl/2008/11/introducing-wcf-clearusernamebinding.html

Comment: I'm guessing you don't want to completely disable security (temporarily of course)?  If you do, you would disable the message security on your wshttp binding like so: `<security mode="None">`

Answer (score 20):

You need to sign the service with a certificate. You can do this by adding the following to the configuration:

```
<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />

        *<serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="certificatename" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
        </serviceCredentials>*
     </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

Where certificatename is the name of your certificate. To create a certificate you can look here:
[Create a self signed certificate](http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html)

Comment: Because it is an internal service I'm currently not interested in applying transport level security and I don't want to create a certificate, because this complicates rolling out the service. Can I configure this without a certificate?

Comment: No unfortunately you have to create a certificate, even for internal testing. You can create your own root level certification authority certificate and then use this to issue a second certificate for your service. Both need to be installed on each server you roll out to.

Comment: I still get this error even with this certificate present. What gives?

Comment: Did you find the issue? I am having a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

Setting `<security mode="None">` and commenting the **serviceCertificate** tag inside `<serviceCredentials>` in my Web.config solved the problem for me.
I was having this problem in localhost, so I didn't need these security settings.